# month regex problem in php. validation problem

Tags: php

```
function preveriDatum($string)
{   
    if (preg_match("^(3)?(?(1)[0-1]|(0)?(?(2)[1-9]|[12][0-9]))\.(0)?(?(3)[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[1-9][0-9]{3}$^", $string)) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

is valid for 13.01.2010 but not for 13.1.2010. Can i aso make it valid for 13.1.2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (preg_match("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[012])\.([1-9][0-9]{3})$", $string))
```

Better is of course to use the DateTime class (http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 4):

Good grief, what are you trying to do here?  Can you just put it into a DateTime class and verify it that way?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

For the regex, in any case, you want a * instead of a ? for the 0.  ? requires there to be at least one instance. Instead of (0)? use (0)*.

Answer (score 2):

Change `.(0)?(?(3)[1-9]|1[0-2])` to `.(0)?(?(3)[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])`. Also consider using a date library.